# Username with superscript letter

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-profile

This user has a very strange nickname and I wonder how those characters can be allowed: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/161328/redarrowfx-%e1%b4%b9%e1%b5%92%e1%b5%97%e1%b6%a4%e1%b5%92%e1%b6%b0-%e1%b4%b0%e1%b5%89%e1%b6%b3%e1%b6%a4%e1%b5%8d%e1%b6%b0%e1%b6%b3

I used the tag "bug" since I think it is one according to this enormous link to user's profile.

Noticed this on the very current question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280210/no-pokemons-on-my-nearby-list-and-no-pokestops-and-gyms-show-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode names are allowed, and as long as they are not [problematic](https://eeemo.net/), or do not meet the criteria for usernames generally (rude/abusive) they're fine.

Comment: So the system would even allow me a user name from your posted link?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 The system may allow it, but if it could be perceived as deliberately troublesome, it could be reset. [Be Nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Accroding to the link the unicodes are counted as more than one character. Wouldn't be there a limit. My profile link - as example - is only 1/3 of it.

Comment: I do not know for sure, but the length calculation being in bytes rather than characters is highly likely.